# Modbus on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, modbus

I am quite new to Raspberry Pi and [Modbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus).
I am going to implement a Modbus RTU on Raspberry Pi using [`libmodbus`](http://libmodbus.org/).

I followed [this totorial](http://www.ostafichuk.com/raspberry-pi-projects/modbus-on-the-pi/modbus-on-the-pi-part-1-compiling-a-basic-example/) as a simple Modbus test, but when I compile the `bandwidth-server-one` and run the code, nothing happens and look like it's stuck in a loop.

Should I use more specialized hardware or change the code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do the people who wrote the linked article suggest?

Comment: nothing! i want to implement modbus rtu. and i am using usb to ttl converter and connect my pi to pc with windows.  and use one of modbus simulator in my pc to act as modbus master or slave.